# problem ( BadMethodCallException:) when do two authentications in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

**I need to do authentications one:for web in table (user) ... and two: for API in another table (user_api) … who in web Laravel using make:auth its working good. So I'm using JWT for API in register, it's working good and gives me a token, but in login it gives me an error**

> BadMethodCallException: Method [guard] does not exist. in file
>   C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\project
>   web\laravel_pro\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php on line 419

**this is the controller**

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');

    try {
        if (!$token =JWTAuth::guard('users_api')->attempt($credentials)){
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }

    } catch (JWTExcption $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

**this is the config**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',

    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'users_api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users_api',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'users_api'=>[
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User_api::class,

    ],
```

Comment: Laravel's cache needs to clear. Maybe that is the issue. try "php artisan cache:clear"

Comment: does my config true or false ??>I tryid  doing  php artisan cache:clear  but aloes i't  not working ...did you understand what my problem  and what I need

Comment: Can you show the error that comes on the command prompt while running command?